# Are there travel magazines that focus on the other Canadian provinces and territories, besides BC and Yukon?

Tags: canada, online-resources

Planning for some trips this spring and summer, my grandfather has found (at Indigo bookstore) and been reading [Yukon, North of Ordinary (magazine)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukon,_North_of_Ordinary_%28magazine%29) and [British Columbia Magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Columbia_Magazine); but  bizarrely even after consulting [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_travel_magazines), he has found no  magazines that similarly restrict their content to one specific province or territory, for any other provinces and territories in Canada.

Comment: @Tom: The entitled question, which, repeated, is: Are there travel magazines that focus on the other Canadian provinces and territories, besides BC and Yukon?

Comment: Sorry, not enough coffee yet :(

Comment: @Tom No problem; sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Prairies North

Voila Quebec - http://www.voilaquebec.com/

Westworld Alberta